# How to append two image tags in div tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

Iam trying to place two image tags with different images/src values init, but in the end two image tags have been appended with same src value instead of different. May i know what s wrong with append:

```
$("<div/>", {
  "id": 'card'+i,
  "class": blockArr[k],
  html: $("<img src='"+key+"'/><img src='_ls-global/layout-images/layout2.png'/>")

}).appendTo("#gtable");
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply plain HTML in this case:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2VQp/)

```
$("<div/>", {
  id: 'card'+i,
  class: blockArr[k],
  html: "<img src='"+key+"'/><img src='_ls-global/layout-images/layout2.png'/>"
}).appendTo("#gtable");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$("<div/>", {
  "id": 'card'+i,
  "class": blockArr[k],
}).html("<img src='"+key+"'/><img src='_ls-global/layout-images/layout2.png'/>")
  .appendTo("#gtable");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#someDiv').append('<img src='someurl1' />');
$('#someDiv').append('<img src='someurl2' />');
```

Just use the append function